# How to make model property to editable in djagno admin panel

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

When I tried to add property into the list_editable into the Django admin.py file, I got an error when running the server.

```
<class 'test_project.admin.SalesAdmin'>: (admin.E100) The value of 'list_editable[2]' refers to 'amount', which is not an attribute of 'test_project.Sales'.
```

Comment: post your model and admin codes

Comment: That is because `amount` is a property of the model that is rendered within python, not a field in your database. If you want to make the field editable, you'll have to write custom logic for it.